# Que répondre quand quelqu'un dit « excusez-moi » alors qu'il n'y a vraiment pas lieu de le dire ?

Tags: politesse

Si quelqu'un utilise cette formule de politesse relativement soutenue (par comparaison à « je m'excuse »), comment lui communiquer sans ambiguïté, dans un langage non moins soutenu et tout en étant grammaticalement correct, qu'il ne m'a aucunement dérangé ?

Answer (score 3):

La réponse qui me parait la plus naturelle et du même registre en réponse à ***excusez-moi*** est :

> ***je vous en prie***.

Answer (score 2):

Les réponse proposées par @guillaume31 conviennent très bien. D'autres réponses idiomatiques pourraient être "De rien" ou "Il n'y a pas de quoi" (utilisée plus famillièrement l'expression serait prononcée "Yapadkwa", mais si vous détachez correctement les mots c'est du français soutenu).

Attention au contexte d'utilisation et au ton du "Excusez-moi". Pour de vraies demandes d'excuse qur quelque chose d'anodin les réponses précédentes s'appliquent, mais "Excusez-moi" (ou "Pardon") peut aussi être employé par avance, par exemple lorsqu'on se fraie un chemin dans une foule avant de pousser les gens, ou simplement pour attirer l'attention de quelqu'un d'occupé.

Dans ce cas on ne répond généralement rien, ou un simple "Oui" indiquant que la demande a été entendue. Si la demande est moins bien reçue, la réponse pourrait être un "Oui" interrogatif un peu plus aggressif ou un "Qu'est-ce qu'il y a ?" agacé, voire (plus soutenu et ancien) "Plaît-il ?"

Mais si vous n'êtes pas agaçé et accueillez l'interruption, un "Je suis à vous!" (ou "Je suis à toi") serait tout à fait correct et très soutenu.

Answer (score 0):

« Excusez-moi » me parait plutôt moins soutenu que « je m'excuse », en tout cas en France et Belgique.

On peut y répondre :

> Ce n'est rien

> Ne vous excusez pas!

> Vous ne me dérangez pas / ne m'avez pas derangé

Comment: "Excusez-moi" ou "Je vous présente mes excuse" est la forme correcte. "Je m'excuse" est une formule famillière courante et très utilisée, mais incorrecte. On ne s'excuse pas soi-même on demande à la personne qu'on a offensé de nous excuser.

Comment: Oui, je parlais de registre de langage, pas de correction. Je n'entends quasiment jamais "je m'excuse" dans des conversations de la vie courante, l'usage me parait vieilli voire ampoulé...

Comment: Désolé! Je n'ai pas été clair. "Je m'excuse" est grammaticalement correct, s'excuser est bien un verbe pronominal. Mais formulé ainsi, cela devient une phrase performative qui retire leur valeur aux excuses : l'interlocuteur n'a plus la possibilité de les accepter ou non, il n'existe plus! Beaucoup de gens considèrent donc "je m'excuse" comme impoli. C'est vrai aussi dans une moindre mesure pour 'Excusez-moi' qui est un impératif (mais au moins on reconnait l'existence de l'interlocuteur). Après on peut dire "Je vous présente mes (plus plates) excuses". Là c'est carrément ampoulé

Comment: @kriss après avoir interrogé plusieurs générations de mon entourage, « je m’excuse » est considéré comme plus formel et utilisé grosso modo moins de 5% du temps par rapport à « excusez-moi ». Sondage qui vaut ce qu’il vaut bien sûr.

Comment: En tout cas « excusez-moi » n’est pas « relativement soutenu » comme l’affirme @peanutjelly.

Comment: "Excusez-moi" est en effet une expression standard assez neutre. Je suis étonné en ce qui concerne les réponses de votre entourage sur "je m'excuse" https://www.academie-francaise.fr/christine-s-france

Comment: Pour "je m'excuse", je ferais une différence entre usage oral et écrit. A l'écrit dans le cadre du discours de l'auteur à son lecteur, je n'y vois pas de contre indication ou de marque d'impolitesse particulière, c'est plutôt une figure de style. A l'oral en usage direct pour moi on est dans le registre famillier, et je l'entends plutôt prononcé avec un accent populaire ou de banlieue.